# Confusion in Aaronson's CHP Paper

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

In section 3 of the paper (https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/chp5.pdf) it states that

> bits $x_{ij}, z_{ij}$ determine the $j$th Pauli matrix $P_j$: $00$ means $I$, $01$ means $X$, $11$ means $Y$, $10$ means $Z$.

But in the following example, the matrix corresponding to the state $|00\rangle$ the $x_{(n+1)1}, z_{(n+1)1} = 01$, so this should correspond to $X$ as the first matrix in the first element of the stabilizer generator. But as it states in the paper itself, the state is stabilized by $+ZI$ and $+IZ$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's an error. Instead of

> bits $x_{ij}, z_{ij}$ determine the $j$th Pauli matrix $P_j$ : $00$ means $I$, $01$ means $\color{red}{X}$, $11$ means $Y$, and $10$ means $\color{red}{Z}$.

it should say

> bits $x_{ij}, z_{ij}$ determine the $j$th Pauli matrix $P_j$ : $00$ means $I$, $01$ means $\color{green}{Z}$, $11$ means $Y$, and $10$ means $\color{green}{X}$.

This is hinted at by the names given to the two bits: $x_{ij}$ indicates whether the operator "contains"$^1$ $X$, i.e. whether it is $X$ or $Y$ and $z_{ij}$ indicates whether the operator "contains" $Z$, i.e. whether it is $Z$ or $Y$.

---

<sup>$^1$ This can be made precise using the fact that the Pauli group is generated by $i$, $X$ and $Z$.</sup>